# Joining sf shapefile data frame with external tibble gives errors

Tags: r, geospatial, shapefile, r-sp, r-sf

I'm Trying to plot polygon data on a map of the Netherlands with the following shape file.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

download.file("http://www.imergis.nl/shp/2018-Imergis_gemeentegrenzen_kustlijn-shp.zip", "shapefile.zip")
unzip("shapefile.zip")

shp <- st_read("2018-Imergis_gemeentegrenzen_kustlijn.shp")
```

Now if I plot te simple feature collection directly it works, the following plots all the municipalities.

```
shp %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_minimal()
```

result:

[image]

But my goal is to join external data `example_df` to the `shp` data frame. Here's my small `example_df`

```
example_df <- structure(list(Gemeente = c("Amsterdam", "Rotterdam"), Beleidscode = c("Vervaardigen harddrugs", 
"Vervaardigen harddrugs"), inwoners_2017 = c(844947L, 634660L
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), vars = c("Gemeente", "Beleidscode"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0L, 1L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    Gemeente = c("Amsterdam", "Rotterdam"), Beleidscode = c("Vervaardigen harddrugs", 
    "Vervaardigen harddrugs")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), vars = c("Gemeente", "Beleidscode"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("Gemeente", 
"Beleidscode")), .Names = c("Gemeente", "Beleidscode", "inwoners_2017"
))


# Convert and rename so that this column is the same example_df
shp <- shp %>% rename(Gemeente = gemeentena) %>%
  mutate(Gemeente = as.character(Gemeente))

shp_joined <- inner_join(shp, example_df, by = Gemeente)
```

First problem: `Error in common_by(by, x, y) : object 'Gemeente' not found` how come? While name and class of `Gemeente` column are the same in the two dataframes?

Second problem, when I try to only plot shp now it's a data.frame the following error occurs:

```
Error in if (st_is_longlat(crs)) bb = trim_bb(bb, margin) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I also have to say that when I installed `sf` package, these warnings occured:

```
==================================================
downloaded 7.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘sf’ ...
** package ‘sf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: clang
configure: CXX: clang++
checking for gdal-config... /usr/local/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 1.11.5
checking GDAL version >= 2.0.0... no
configure: error: sf is not compatible with GDAL versions below 2.0.0
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/Users/Thomas/Library/R/3.3/library/sf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in ...
```

But it does plot the original shape file straight after reading it in `st_read()` and when calling library(sf) it says: `Linking to GEOS 3.4.2, GDAL 2.1.2, proj.4 4.9.1`

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `shp_joined <- inner_join(shp, example_df, by = "Gemeente")`.

I think you need "" for the by argument in the `inner_join`. This is how the `dplyr` conducts the join operation. The by argument needs standard evaluation, unlike other `dplyr` functions that we can use non-standard evaluation there.